# Custom sorting and take first row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv as below

```
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| ID  | version | Name      | State      |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| 101 | 1       | Nut       | In-Transit |
| 101 | 1       | Nut       | Cancelled  |
| 101 | 1       | Nut       | Delivered  |
| 101 | 2       | Nut 2.0   | In-Transit |
| 102 | 1       | Screw     | Shipped    |
| 102 | 1       | Screw     | In-Transit |
| 102 | 2       | Screw 2.0 | Shipped    |
| 102 | 2       | Screw 2.0 | Cancelled  |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Now I want to take the highest state(based on below priority) among all available state for each ID & version combination.

My custom order

1. Delivered
2. In-Transit
3. Shipped
4. Cancelled

Expected output

```
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| ID  | version | Name      | State      |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| 101 | 1       | Nut       | Delivered  |
| 101 | 2       | Nut 2.0   | In-Transit |
| 102 | 1       | Screw     | In-Transit |
| 102 | 2       | Screw 2.0 | Shipped    |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I have tried below query but not working. I'm new to python and i'm not sure how to fix this.

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.read_csv('C:/Mypython/Newyork',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

mydata['state'] = pd.Categorical(mydata['state'], ["Delivered","In-Transit","Shipped","Cancelled"])

mydate.sort_values('state').drop_duplicates(['ID','VERSION'],keep='first')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working correct, it seems there is no assign back to new variable:

```
mydata['State'] = pd.Categorical(mydata['State'], 
                                ["Delivered", "In-Transit", "Shipped", "Cancelled"], 
                                 ordered=True)

#keep='first'is default value, so should be omitted
mydata = mydata.sort_values('state').drop_duplicates(['ID','version'])
print (mydata)
    ID  version       Name       state
2  101        1        Nut   Delivered
3  101        2    Nut 2.0  In-Transit
5  102        1      Screw  In-Transit
6  102        2  Screw 2.0     Shipped
```

Also if want sorted output by `ID`, `version` add sorting by multiple columns:

```
mydata['State'] = pd.Categorical(mydata['State'], 
                                ["Delivered", "In-Transit", "Shipped", "Cancelled"], 
                                 ordered=True)
mydata = mydata.sort_values(['ID','version','state']).drop_duplicates(['ID','version'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Categorical` with `ordered=True` to create a categorical variable then `sort_values` on this categorical variable and use `groupby` on `ID, version` and `agg` using `first`:

```
mydata['State'] = pd.Categorical(mydata['State'], ["Delivered", "In-Transit", "Shipped", "Cancelled"], ordered=True)
df = mydata.sort_values('State').groupby(['ID', 'version'], as_index=False).first()
```

Result:

```
    ID  version       Name       State
0  101        1        Nut   Delivered
1  101        2    Nut 2.0  In-Transit
2  102        1      Screw  In-Transit
3  102        2  Screw 2.0     Shipped
```